# PHPUnit Mocking abstract class with closure binding

Tags: binding, mocking, phpunit, closures, abstract

During the unittesting of an abstract class i ran into a problem that the $this context of a closure is the current testing class and not the mocked abstract class. I need to test the access of certain class attributes from that method, but I cannot get access to the right context. Is there a method to achief this goal?

Example:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {

    /**
    *
    */
    protected $_attributes;

    /**
    *
    */
    public function __construct($attributes) {
        $this->_attributes = $attributes;
    }

    /**
    *
    */
    public abstract function processAttributes();
}

class AbstractClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testAttributesProcessing() {
        $closure =  function() {
                        // $this context is now AbstractClassTest
                        // but the context of AbstractClass is desired
                    };

        $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass("AbstractClass");
        $stub->expects($this->any())
            ->method("processAttributes")
            ->will($this->returnCallback($closure);

        $stub->processAttributes();
    }
}
```

I have tried to bind the closure to the $stub, but the context won't change:

```
$closure->bindTo($stub);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to test exactly? testing on attribute visibility seems a bit odd; you're effectively testing that the PHP internals for 'public','protected' and 'private' work correctly. Which of course they always will do.

Comment: The example is trimmed down, but what it boils down to is that the attributes are set correctly from an other object. It is more directed to an integration test, because of the dependencies between the objects. It comes down to make sure some legacy code doesn't break the new code.

Comment: i don't use closure binding really much and often, but afair you should bind the scope for the closure, too, resulting in smth like `$newlyCreatedClosure = $closure->bindTo($stub, 'AbstractClass');`. Now it should have `$_attributes` accessible. Please also note that original `$closure` remains unchanged, you should apply a `$newlyCreatedClosure`.